# Regex find a comma between two strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to remove commas from a certain place within a text file. The input looks like this:

Y=6","~2807-1 Q12m.  Plate(s), screw(s), rod(s) or pin(s) in any bone - NO"

I only want to remove the commas between the "Y=6","" and the ending double quote. If I use

(?<=Y=\d",").*(?=")

I can isolate the part between those but can't for the life of me figure out how to just get the commas.

Answer (score 0):

- Find: `(?:Y=\d","|\G)[^,"]*\K,`
- Replace: `NOTHING`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VCJ76N/1)

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # start non capture group
    Y=\d    # literally Y= followed by 1 digit. You may want to use \d+ for 1 or more digits
    ","     # literally ","
  |         # OR
    \G      # restart form last match position
)           # end group
[^,"]*      # 0 or more any character that is not comma or double quote
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
,           # a comma
```